# How to checkbox false value and store it on database sql server from data Data Grid view in c#

Tags: c#, .net

pls help me i am stuck in the project and very hard in here.
when i click on the one checkbox in the row which i have set the TrueValue=P in grid view property it store successfuly.but the FalseValue store as null on database. i want to store the 1 instead of the null or 0 so how can i do. it false value i have set in grid view property it didnt work.here is the image of my grid view.
[image]
here is my coding after the image of the grid view which store datafrom grid view into datbase.
[image]

here is image of the database store value which i want to store the zero instead of the empty or null in cell.
[image]

i just want to get the False value of the checkbox should store in database.
thanks.
my code for storing the value of the checkbox in the project.

```
{
      foreach (DataGridViewRow iteam in dtgAttandance.Rows)
      { 
           con.Open();
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO EmpAttandanceDetail Values('"
                +txtAttandID.Text+"','"
                + iteam.Cells[0].Value + "','"
                + iteam.Cells[1].Value + "','"
                + iteam.Cells[2].Value + "','"
                + iteam.Cells[3].Value + "','"
                + iteam.Cells[4].Value + "','"
                + iteam.Cells[5].Value + "','"
                + iteam.Cells[6].Value+ "','"
                + iteam.Cells[7].Value+ "','"
                + iteam.Cells[8].Value+ "')",con);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
       }

       con.Open();
       SqlCommand cmdDetail = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO EmpAttandance values('" + txtAttandID.Text + "','" + dtAttand.Text + "')", con);
       cmdDetail.ExecuteNonQuery();
       MessageBox.Show("Attandance Save Successfully");
       con.Close();
       AttandanceDateVerifier();
}
```

Comment: Oh, and, you have a pretty big security issue in your query builder See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work ... and for the solution use this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: okay i putting my code

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix, you can invert cell 7's value: `+ !((bool)iteam.Cells[7].Value) + "','"` might help, but I urge you to check the `Parameterizing the SqlCommand` links. It will force you to think about data types and will make your problem easier.

Comment: bro solve it by change database type to bit for true or false value.and get the results